# Как протестировать метод вызываемый при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c#, testng

```
private void button_reg_out_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl_magazin.SelectedTab = tabPage_magazin;
        }
```

Как протестировать такой метод или как словить нажатие на кнопку

Comment: сделать его public и тестировать как обычно

Comment: @Grundy, internal же, зачем паблик? Или я не понял вопроса

Comment: Нужно как-то написать тест чтобы вызывать обработчик кнопки и полученный результат сравнить с результатом а именно переключением панели